# Show that $T \mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

$T \mathbb{R}^n$ is the tangent bundle to $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do I show that is is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? I know that there is an isomorphism (and therefore a diffeomorphism) between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$, can I conclude from here, using the fact that $TM$ is the disjoint union of all $T_pM$s?

Alternatively: I know that, if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold, then $TM$ is a $2n$-dimensional differentiable manifold. I have seen the construction given in [Warner, Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups](https://books.google.it/books?id=S_7lBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 19, complete with proof. It really shouldn't be hard to explicitely construct the diffeomorphism, but I'm struggling for ideas.

Comment: There *always* is an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and *some* $\Bbb R^n$ (the same $n$ for all $p$-s), but not all tangent bundles are diffeomorphic to $M\times\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 4):

If $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold defined by the atlas $(U_i,f_i:U_i\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n)_{i\in I}$ then $TM$ is the manifold defined by $(U_i\times\mathbb{R}^n,g_i)$ where $g_i(x,y)=f_i\circ f_j^{-1}(x), d(f_i\circ f_j^{-1})_{f_j(x)}(y))$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold defined by the chart $(\mathbb{R}^n, Id_{\mathbb{R}^n})$, therefore $T\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by the chart $(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n, Id_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify what you exactly mean by "$TM$ is the manifold defined by $(U_i \times \mathbb{R}^n, g_i)$"? My definition is a little different, $TM$ being the manifold with charts $(\pi^{-1}(U), \tilde{\phi})$, where $\pi$ is the projection $TM \mapsto M$, $(U, \phi)$ is a chart on $M$ and, if $(x, v) \in TM$, $\tilde{\phi} (x, v) = (x_1(\pi(v)), \dots, x_n(\pi(v)), (dx_1)_|{p} (v), \dots, (dx_n)_{|p} (v))$

Answer (score 0):

Going by Lee's definition, the tangent bundle is, by definition, disjoint union of all $T_pM  $s.
Let $(U,\phi)$ be in atlas of M. Define map $f: \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow R^{2n} $ as $$f\Bigg(v^i|\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Bigg|_p \Bigg)=(p,v) $$
Now write down the inverse of $f$ and observe that it is a bijection. Now write down the map $ id\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$. This should in fact turn out to be identity map.